# google map API before / after function (like ajax)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to put a loading icon before finding or I need catch find location start/end function (like ajax before/success function)

I could not find any resources related to this .I want to do; When you click on the "Find current location" button, you will see a small icon. Hide the icon when the process is finished

I use javascript without jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) code, I added `<div id="loader"></div>` inside `<div id="floating-panel"></div>`.In this I have added image tag  when `geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap)` is called. You can change with desired icon

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });

}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = "<img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif'>"
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = ""
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = ""
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
  /*google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    alert()
});*/

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Yess !. Exactly as I want